# Do worn out tires effect the brake pad, rotor and shocks?

Tags: honda, tires, brake-rotor, shock-absorber, brake-pad

My tires are worn out and the mechanic suggested that if I don't change them then it will cause negative impact on the brake pad, rotor and shocks? Is this true.

Car is done 150000 kms and braking was causing my steering to vibrate. So the mechanic recently changed the bearings, tie rod, brake rotors and pads. Tires were old. But steering is vibrating when braking so he has now changed to new tires. But steering is still vibrating on breaking. So he thinks old tires caused damage to rotor or pads.

Comment: Your "mechanic" has no idea what the problem is, and is randomly changing parts, at *your expense*, in the hope that either a) the problem will be solved or, preferably b) you'll keep coming back and giving him or her more money. Rotors or bearings or a *loose* tie rod will contribute to vibration, as can other things. Tires will not unless the wheel to which they are attached is attempting to separate from the vehicle, or is about to explode.

Answer (score 4):

No worn out tires will not affect brakes rotors or shocks.

But using this mechanic will affect your wallet in a negative way :)

It is a bad thing when a mechanic uses the customers lack of knowledge to gain more money.

This beeing said it is possible you need to replace brake pads shocks or weel bearings but this is not connected to the wear of your tires.

After you edited your question i can see the parts have been replaced but i leave my answer unchanged.

Too high air pressure might cause more wear on the shocks and bearings and the same will poorly balaneced weels,but you will feel it in your car when you drive it long before any damage takes place.

Comment: He recently changed the bearings, tie rod, brake rotors and pads. But steering is vibrating when braking so he changed tires. But it is still vibrating on breaking. So he thinks old tires caused damage to brake rotor or pads.. How can I confront him.

Comment: so he did change bearings and brake pads rotors and shocks and this did not help and he changed the tires too and still the same problem,it sounds to me like some thing else is wrong.i do not know how you can confront him except telling him that you paid him to get the car fixed and that he have not fulfilled his part of the deal.

Comment: Shock was not changed. Could that be the cause. I think not because bad shocks would cause steering to vibrate a high speed. And not only when braking. My steering vibrates only when braking

Comment: no the shocks will not cause vibration when you are braking unless you lock the weels,if you only have shaking when you brake the weels are fine so the cause is the rotors,did your mechanic realy change the rotors if he did atleast one of them are faulty.with the information you have given this have to be the cause no pads no weels no shocks no bearings.

Comment: The symptoms point to warped rotor(s). Did the steering vibration stop for awhile after the rotors were replaced, and then come back later? If yes, you may have caliper or brake hose problems. If it never went away, it shouldn't have left the shop as repaired. You might want to talk to this mechanic and get things straightened out as much as you can. Find another reputable shop to inspect vehicle afterwards. Sorry for your frustrations.

Comment: He changed by stock normal rotors to ones with holes and told me they are sports. I'll get the rotors checked now

Comment: I would also rotate/swap position of your wheels/ tyres to rule out if it is a tyre/rim balancing problem.

Answer (score 0):

Things that can cause vibration felt through the steering wheel: *(Some of these have already been addressed on your car)*

1. Wheel out of balance. When a tire is installed, weights must be affixed to the rim (wheel, which is not the same thing as the tire) at specific places, determined by the use of a balance machine. If you lose a weight (pretty common in my experience), the thing will bounce and/or vibrate, which you can feel throughout the car. This process is analogous to what many of us did in school when using a centrifuge. Insert the important test tube into the machine, and insert an empty test tube on the opposite side. If you don't do that, the machine either tears itself apart or the important tube flies off and shatters.
2. Wheel not correctly affixed to the hub. I very recently had this happen because my 4Runner had, unbeknownst to me, three broken wheel studs. This is very, very, bad.
3. "Warped" brake rotor. It's worth noting that rotors don't really warp - they wear unevenly, leading to having non-uniformly distributed mass. This has the same effect as an improperly balanced wheel.
4. Lug nuts improperly torqued. With enough wiggle room, the wheel... wiggles.
5. Bad wheel bearing.
6. Bad tie rod bushings.
7. Steering rack play. If that was the case, you'd sense it even when driving in a parking lot. This would be really, really obvious to even the most incompetent mechanic.
8. Suspension bushings. Big rubber parts that absorb some of the backlash in the system. These tend to crack and leak over time. With nearly 100k miles on your car, it's not unexpected to have to replace a few of these. (There are ~12 on the front suspension in a modern RWD car. It is VERY easy to see this problem by looking at the bushings, and the mechanic should have checked that already.)
9. Play in the steering column rack & pinion. Unlikely, and this is more likely to cause steering play rather than vibration.

**TL;DR**

Find a new mechanic, and ask for a guarantee that repairs you pay for will fix the problem. This is not uncommon and, at least in Texas, many shops guarantee this.

The most likely causes are rotors, wheel bearings or bushings (IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the state of the tire, if your tracking is out it can cause irregular wear and that will affect the grip of your tires on the road.

Comment: the question is not about the weel alignment,it is well known that this can wear out the tires fast.the question is about shaking when the op aply the brakes.